# Create a boolean dataframe based on the difference between two datetimes

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, boolean

I have a pandas dataframe called "gaps" that looks like this:

```
Index    Gap in days
0        2 days 00:00:00
1        8 days 00:00:00
2        4 days 00:00:00
3        15 days 00:00:00
...
201      21 days 00:00:00
```

The date format has been converted to the standard datetime format. I want to create a simple boolean dataframe that returns TRUE if the gap in days is more than 7 days, and FALSE otherwise.

My initial attempt was the simple:

```
morethan7days = gaps > 7
```

For which I get the error:

```
TypeError: invalid type comparison
```

Anybody know what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, I got the answer through trial and error:

```
morethan7days = gaps > datetime.timedelta(days=7)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert `timedeltas` to days by [`Series.dt.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.days.html) and then compare by integer:

```
gaps = df['Gap in days']
morethan7days = gaps.dt.days > 7
print (morethan7days)
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
4     True
Name: Gap in days, dtype: bool
```

Another solution is compare with [`pandas.Timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Timedelta.html):

```
gaps = df['Gap in days']
morethan7days = gaps > pd.Timedelta(7, unit='d')
```